# Grid layout not aligning names

Tags: css, wordpress, buddypress

I followed a tutorial to customize a members page for a website I designed, but I can't figure out where my CSS is incorrect. The member names are not lining up under the avatars.

http://www.northeastrunningclub.org/members/

Tutorial: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-buddypress-members-directory/

I tried changing a couple things to no avail. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.item-avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 65px;
}
```